# Multiple Curve Guides act wird

Tags: animation, particles, bezier-curves

I have set up Curve Guide. It will be used for showing how particles are moving inside of pipe.

[image: CurveGuide SetUp 1]

[image: CurveGuide SetUp 2]

The particles need to be insisde of 'pipe' object, so I thought that the best particles behaviour would be achived by Curve guides, as particles are good girls in this scenario and they don't fly away or something like that .

The set up works wonderful until I don't Duplicate Collection to create another CurveGuide System... Particles are being 'distracted' by the close Curve Guides...

[image: Particles acting crazy because of 2 CurveGuides]

In final animation the particles in the pipes will be close to eachother, and each particle system needs to be inside of his 'pipe object', it will be something around 36 pipes. The pipes will be slightly different so instance copy won't work.

How to set up these Curve Guides to only effect one particle system for one Curve Guide?

Answer (score 1):

[image: The solution]

Ok, I found the option. We need to "Use Max" (Curves' Force settings) in this kind of situation (for all Guide Curves in the scene) :)